# Pandas with mapped modification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames; `df1` has two columns called `A` and `B` and looks like:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[10,30], 'B':[5,4]})
A    B
10   5
30   4
```

`df2` has two columns `B` and `C`, and looks like:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(data={'B':[4,7], 'B':[10,20]})
B    C
4    10
7    20
```

I want to modify `df1.A` based on if `df1.B` matches `df2.B`. If so, `df1.A` should divide `df2.C`. Namely, I want to get the following with the aforementioned `df1` and `df2`:

```
A    B
10   5
3    4
```

Is there a one-line solution in Python?

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially `merge` with some manipulation:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='B', how='left')
    .assign(C=lambda x: x.C.fillna(1))  # those don't match has `C` value `1`
    .assign(A=lambda x: x.A/x.C)        # divide by `C` value
    .drop('C', axis=1)                  # remove the `C` column
)
```

Output:

```
      A  B
0  10.0  5
1   3.0  4
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `map`

```
d = dict(zip(df2.B, df2.C))
f = lambda x: d.get(x, 1)
df1.assign(A=df1.A / df1.B.map(f))

      A  B
0  10.0  5
1   3.0  4
```